# Find a text in a file and Insert a text after it

Tags: awk, sed

I have a text file. The text file contains the below content.

```
ServerName
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot
```

I need to insert a text `www.mydomain.com`, after the `ServerName`.
Is there any command to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
sed 's/^\(ServerName\)$/\1 www.mydomain.com/' file.txt
```

The captured group, `\(ServerName\)` is used in the replacement pattern as `\1`.

Editing the file in place, with backup, assuming the GNU, `ssed`, busybox or some BSD implementations of `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak 's/^\(ServerName\)$/\1 www.mydomain.com/' file.txt
```

The original file will be kept as `file.bak` and the modified file will be `file.txt.bak`.

Editing in place, without backup (GNU, `ssed` or `busybox` only):

```
sed -i 's/^\(ServerName\)$/\1 www.mydomain.com/' file.txt
```

(for BSDs, use `sed -i '' 's/...`).

---

Even shorter, without any captured group:

```
sed -i 's/^ServerName$/& www.mydomain.com/' file.txt
```

Here `&` will be replaced by the match.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed --in-place 's/ServerName/& www.example.com/' /path/to/apache-vhost.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sed substitue command:

```
sed -i 's/ServerName/ServerName www.mydomain.com/' file.txt
```

Comment: after ServerName , no under ServerName (no new line)

Comment: @Babyy Right! Misread the question! :P